# How to change the value of a button in Python (Flask)

Tags: python, html, flask, button

I want to change the value of a button written in html to "records". I want to adress and change the button in python. This is in order to prevent to tap the record button twice as the request form changes and to get a visual feedback that it works.

**this is what i have:**

```
@app.route('/camera', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def camera(): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['record'] == 'record here' :  # <-------- here I ask what the value of the button 
            print ("is recording")                    #           is and it works fine
            p1 = threading.Thread(target=recording)
            p1.start()
    return render_template('camera.html')
```

**this is what i want:**

```
@app.route('/camera', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def camera(): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['record'] == 'record here' :
            print ("is recording")
            p1 = threading.Thread(target=recording)
            p1.start()
            request.form['record'] = 'records' :     # <----------------- Something like this
    return render_template('camera.html')
```

I am a newbie in python html flask and web development in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking to do should be done through JavaScript, because the most natural way to change the label of the button is through client-side programming.

However, if you insist on doing this from server-side code, you can start by changing the template `camera.html`. Let's say that you have the following button in your template:

```html
<input type="submit" name="record" value="record here">
```

This should be changed to include a variable:

```html
<input type="submit" name="record" value="{{ record }}">
```

Now you can send the value of this variable using `render_template`:

```py
@app.route('/camera', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def camera(): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['record'] == 'record here' :
            print ("is recording")
            p1 = threading.Thread(target=recording)
            p1.start()
            return render_template('camera.html', record='records')
    return render_template('camera.html', record='record here')
```

Comment: Do you know how to update it back to "record here" when the recording is finished?, the second render template is not reached. I have tried pyautogui to refresh it but even when you refresh the page it does not work

Comment: @KevinKeller in your code, refreshing the webpage should do it (Vistiting the page without sending anything). Because when you refresh the page, you are actually doing a GET request, and in that case `request.method == 'POST'` will be `False` and the last `return` in `camera` will be run.

Comment: Yes I understand and I've tried it but for some reason it wont update even with a hard refresh on pyautogui

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with `pyautogui` so I have no idea on how you are writing this program. But if this idea works in a standard browser, then the problem might be from `pyautogui`. Also make sure that the page is not cached. In a normal browser, you should refresh the page with Shift+F5 to get a full refresh without using the cache.

Answer (score 2):

What I noticed from your code is that you want to change the value of a button in camera.html page to 'records'.

To do so, you should pass 'records' as an argument to render_html and receive it in camera.html and assign it to the button's value.

```
@app.route('/camera', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def camera(): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['record'] == 'record here' :
            print ("is recording")
            p1 = threading.Thread(target=recording)
            p1.start()
            request.form['record'] = 'records' :
    return render_template('camera.html', val='records')
```

Now in your camera.html you have a, say button or input, with a name 'records':

```
{% if val!=None and val!="" %}
<input type="submit" name="records", value="{{val}}" />
{% else %}
<input type="submit" name="records", value="record here" />
{% endif %}
```